# Defining a new command whose argument doesn't need braces

Tags: macros, lists, itemize

I created a `\newcommand` to allow me to quickly create one-item lists.

`\newcommand{\itemm}[1]{\begin{itemize}\item #1 \end{itemize}}`

When I used `\item`, I don't have to put braces around the text. Is there a way I can allow my new macro `\itemm` to work without braces?

e.g.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Pennsylvania    % no braces works fine
\end{itemize}


\itemm {Philadelphia}  % \itemm currently requires braces
                       % or only the first character is itemized
\itemm Pittsburg       % I would like \itemm to not require braces
                       % and to itemize the entire string
```

Comment: This really won't end well, but you can define a custom end-character if you bop down to the lower-level TeX primitive `\def`: `\def\itemm#1@{This command must be used with an ending @}`.  The use `\itemm some text @` would, I *think*, put `{some text }` into `#1`.

Comment: The problem with your desire is that there is no way to tell where the `\item` is supposed to end.

Comment: You could define something like a subparagraph (or create a new sectioning level) that would  _emulate_ the behaviour of itemize.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to replace a feature of good editor with bad LaTeX. Your editor should be able to learn new commands and insert all kind of braces properly automagically. Which editor are you using?

Comment: "entire string" is not defined, you appear to want to take up to the next paragraph (and only allow one paragraph???) that's possible but would be against the latex syntax, latex goes to some lengths to give commands a consistent syntax. The end of each item is marked by the next `\item` or the `\end{itemize}`

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, this might be a bad idea, since it is inconsistent with LaTeX syntax. The reason braces are not used within `itemize` is that it is already in an environment. The text is not the argument of `\item` as much as `\item` indicates where the text should be divided. In your usage however, the text should really be seen as an argument of `\itemm`, so braces are appropriate.

That said, it can be achieved with the plain tex `\def`.

```
\def\itemm #1 {\begin{itemize}\item #1\end{itemize}}
```

The defined command takes everything up to the next whitespace (space, tab or linebreak, but not a fixed space `~`) as argument.